# Extract an 8 character integer string from an ical file

Tags: php, icalendar, rfc5545

This code to get all sequences of 8 integers works fine:

`preg_match_all('/[0-9]{8}/', $string, $match);`

However I am only interested if the match starts with 20.

I know I have to add  `^20` somewhere but I have tried many times with no success. I have looked at many regex tutorials but none of them seems to explain how to do 2 separate searches.

I am actually trying to parse ICAL files to extract the dates. If the 8 digit integer starts with 20 it almost certainly is a date.

For example: `DTSTART:20150112T120000Z`

Comment: Have you tried `(?=20)(\d{8})` ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution:

```
/(20)\d{6}/
```

Comment: I'd use /(20\d{6})/ to get the whole match instead of the 20 only.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably find what you are looking for:

```
(?=20)(\d{8})
```

It does a positive lookahead to capture a group if it starts with `20` along with a 8 digit number.

Answer (score 0):

The answer highly depends on what you want to achieve. Do you want to extract all and any dates from an icalendar file. If so, you might be missing birthday dates as their year are most likely to be starting with 19xx.

Also matching any dates will yield most likely many undesired dates like `UNTIL`, `TRIGGER`, `DTEND`, ...

Assuming from your example you want to extract events start dates, you could try:

```
DTSTART[a-zA-Z._%+-/=;]*:(\d){8}[T]?[\d]{6}
```

To be kept in mind: following `DTSTART` can be a timezone definition like `TZID=America/New_York` and/or the type definition `DATE` or `DATE-TIME` (see [RFC5545 DATE-TIME](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.2.4)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. 
The first 2 answers are perfect for my needs because I am only interested in the future. This is the function I made 


    function extract_numbers($string)
    {
     
    preg_match_all('/(201\d{5})/', $string, $match);
    //Find a number which starts with 201 followed by 5 integers

    return $match[0];
    }